# Как сгенерировать звуковой сигнал?

Tags: аудио

Требуется сгенерировать звуковой сигнал определенной продолжительности, частота которого будет возрастать со временем. Как этого добиться? Подозреваю, что эта задача решается с помощью ассемблера.

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае гуглите формат RAW PCM, я на дельфях с сигналом извращался. Там, грубо говоря, если сигнал 44100 Hz, 16bps, значит, в течение секунды пройдет ((16 / 8) * каналы * 44100) байт. Для стерео получится 196400 байт.

Т.е. суть в генерации этого потока, делфи с реалтаймом вполне справлялся. Он для проигрывания напрямую, на звуковуху, потому его для сохранения надо конвертить во что-то другое, обычно WAV.

На asm, конечно, логичнее, но вот вам пример синусоиды

```
сэмпл: signed int{bps}
секундаЗаписи: массив сэмплов [0..{Hz*Channels}-1]
каналы: Channels
for (N1 = 0..{Hz-1})
  for (N2 = 0..(каналы-1))
    секундаЗаписи[N1*2 + N2] = синус(Пи * (N1 / (Hz/2))) * максимально_значение_для_signed_int{bps}
играть(секундаЗаписи)
```

Вот и смотрите по нагрузке, справится ваш обработчик или нужно подключать ассемблер.

Comment: Как сделать это на С++? Может стоит задействовать встроенный ассемблер и потом запихнуть всё это в удобную функцию. Есть варианты? Поиск не помог.

Comment: Под дельфями я пользовался <a href="http://www.un4seen.com/">Bass Audio Library</a>, там и под кресты есть.

Comment: @Вячеслав Кириченко, <a href="http://www.google.ru/search?q=libsndfile">=)</a>

Comment: Не прощё ли использовать функцию Beep() без подключения каких-либо внешних библиотек. Сомневаюсь, что я смогу из неё выжить то, что требуется, но вероятнее всего это более оптимальный вариант. Просто не охота таскать за собой лишний груз не используемого функционала.

Comment: Это всего лишь мой опыт) В моем случае либа была оптимальной, т.к. только искажениями дело не ограничивалось - и эта прелесть и файл с инета откроет(в т.ч. вещание), и с харда откроет,  и сконвертит в том же реалтайме, и каналы замиксует. В общем вот. Просто подать на звуковуху сигнал можно, наверно, и более простыми средствами, но тут я пас.

Comment: Добрый вечер, Sh4dow, =)

Comment: Вообще можно и без bass, просто через вин-апишный PlaySound сделать, эта функция как раз RAW PCM и воспроизводит, причем в фоне.

Answer (score -2):

Пример генерации звука (8 бит, моно, 44100 Гц) и проигрывание его средствами WinAPI (winmm.dll):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Winmm.lib")

typedef struct s_riff_header {
    FOURCC riff_sign; // "RIFF"
    DWORD data_size;
    FOURCC wave_sign; // "WAVE"
    FOURCC fmt_sign; // "fmt "
    DWORD fmt_size;
    // WAVEFORMATEX
    WORD wFormatTag;
    WORD nChannels;
    DWORD nSamplesPerSec;
    DWORD nAvgBytesPerSec;
    WORD nBlockAlign;
    WORD wBitsPerSample;
    // end of WAVEFORMATEX structure
    FOURCC data_sign; // "data"
    DWORD samples;
} RIFF_HEADER;

void sound(int freq) {
    static RIFF_HEADER hdr = {
        FOURCC_RIFF,
        0,
        mmioFOURCC('W','A','V','E'),
        mmioFOURCC('f','m','t',' '),
        16,
        1,
        1, // mono
        44100,
        44100,
        1,
        8, // 8 bit per sample
        mmioFOURCC('d','a','t','a'),
        0
    };
    static BYTE * sound_buff;
    BYTE * samples;
    int i,numSamples,size;
    
    if(freq > 0 && freq <= 22050) {
        numSamples = ceil(44100.0 / freq);
        size = sizeof(RIFF_HEADER) + numSamples;
        sound_buff = (BYTE *)malloc(size);
        
        hdr.data_size = size-8;
        hdr.samples = numSamples;
        
        memcpy(sound_buff, &hdr, sizeof(RIFF_HEADER));
        
        samples = sound_buff+sizeof(RIFF_HEADER);
        for(i=0;i<numSamples;i++)
            samples[i] = floor(127*sin(6.28/numSamples*i)+128);
        
        PlaySound((char *)sound_buff, 0, SND_ASYNC+SND_LOOP+SND_MEMORY);
    }
    else {
        PlaySound(NULL,0,SND_ASYNC);
        free(sound_buff);
    }
}

int main() {
    int i;
    // Звуки от 440 до 5000 Гц с возрастанием частоты на *1.06 (примерно полутон)
    for(i=440;i<5000;i*=1.06) {
        sound(i);
        Sleep(100);
        sound(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

В данном случае заполняется массив сэмплов только для одной полной волны на данной частоте. Плюс - экономия памяти. Минус - при переходе на другую частоту слышен щелчек. Выход - заполнять блок сэмплов для всего времени звучания, во время заполнения менять частоту нужным образом.

Comment: Что-то не компилируется. Гора ошибок.

Comment: Чем компилируете, какая первая ошибка и в какой строке?

Comment: "s_riff_header::riff_sign: переполнение границ массива".
Также ошибки типа "невозможно преобразовать одно в другое". 

Компилировал на VS 2010.

Comment: Подправил инициализацию заголовка.

Comment: Код не работал, пришлось подправить. Теперь новая беда
>ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ `__imp__PlaySoundW@12` в функции "`void __cdecl sound(int)`" (?sound@@YAXH@Z)

Comment: Нашел, нужно добавить `#pragma comment(lib, "Winmm.lib")` после инклудов.

Comment: Самое интересное, что компилируется, запускается и... тишина.

Comment: Странно, у меня нормально, пищит)
P.S. протестировал под Win7 (до этого на WinXP), если под XP между "нотами" были просто щелчки, то тут небольшие паузы. В общем нужно целиком буфер заполнять.